# GDB Backtrace doesn't show function names with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb

In my CMakeLists file, at the very end I have `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)`. However, when I try to do a backtrace, all I get is

```
#0  Car::setTexture (this=0x10025cc20, tex=...)
#1  0x0000000100002a0f in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000020000000 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000020000000 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000120000000 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000010023ce90 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000008000000060 in ?? ()
```

So far, everything else I've tried with debugging (`list`, etc) has worked fine. Only the backtraces are missing the function names. However, when I regenerate the build files with the cmake `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` commented out, the debugging symbols are missing (as expected), but the backtrace function calls are shown.

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000001000056b4 in Car::setTexture(TRTexture) ()
#1  0x0000000100002a0f in SDLWrapper::loadSprite(Sprite*) ()
#2  0x0000000100004654 in TypeRight::startGame() ()
#3  0x0000000100001cc8 in main ()
```

Comment: Call `make VERBOSE=1` to see which parameters are added to your build. You can set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` to `-O0 -g2` to get the full back-trace.

Comment: Tried it. Here's one of the libraries 
`/usr/bin/c++    -O0 -g2 -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/local/include -I/gtest/include -I/gtest    -o CMakeFiles/TRTexture_lib.dir/TRTexture.cpp.o -c TRTexture.cpp`
(I truncated some of the paths in this comment)

Comment: It should work with these flags. If not, is not a CMake issue but you have to try a minimal example without CMake and get that properly compiled with debug information.

Comment: Making it without cmake and using those flags was successful. I get correct backtraces. It only was unsuccessful when using cmake with those flags.

Comment: Maybe `strip --strip-debug`  or somethign like that is called when final binary is called? Please check how it is linked.

Comment: `/usr/bin/c++   -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o  -o main  -lSDL2 -L"/usr/local/lib" -lSDL2_image libsdlwrapper_lib.a libTypeRight_lib.a libBruh_l
ib.a libsdlwrapper_lib.a libSprite_lib.a libSpriteFactory_lib.a libsdlwrapper_lib.a libSprite_lib.a libSpriteFactory_lib.a libTRTexture_lib.a -lSDL2 -L"/usr/local/lib" -lSDL2_image`

Nope. No stripping.

Comment: Not sure what's cmake's problem with set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE...), but doing cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug does work as expected.

Comment: BTW: I have built cmake 3.2.1 from source and now set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE...) suddenly works as expected. It looks like a bug in version bundled with ubuntu 14.04 (2.8.12...).

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I regenerate the build files with the cmake set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) commented out, the debugging symbols are missing (as expected), but the backtrace function calls are shown.

The most likely cause: you are pointing GDB at the wrong executable.

As far as I understand, changing `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` changes the build output directory, and if you have not adjusted your GDB command for that, *and* if you  are attaching to a running process rather than running from inside GDB, then that would explain all the symptoms you've observed.